# Weird performance effects when reducing Java garbage collection

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I ran into a weird effects when doing a simple restructuring of my program to reduce garbage collection. The effect is that unrelated code gets consistently about 20% slower.

The scenario is pretty simple: I have a hierarchy of methods, where method A calls method B and B calls C1 and C2. A calls B inside a loop. Ab, B C1 and C2 are used to build a a large tree structure.

I need to pass data between C1 and C2, so I created a buffer object in B that I first pass in to C1 to initialise it and then into C2 to consume it. Since B is called about 5,000,000 times, this caused a considerable of GC, apparently about 170MB of GC.

As optimisation, I decided to create the buffer object in A and then pass in it to B to be used in C1 and C2.

Result: the amount of GC went down to almost 0. 
However, I have several other methods parallel to A (that never call A, B, C1, or C2), which access the same data that is create by A, B, C1, C2. All these access method get a performance hit of about 20% when using the optimisation.

I have the following two suspicions, but I'm not sure how to confirm them:

1. I know the JVM can restructure objects in memory to optimise memory locality and improve CPU cache performance. Cold that be a problem?
2. The method signatures get bigger. Is there a limit in JVM (or CPUs in general) that make method calls more expensive if the argument list crosses a certain threshold?

I'm using Oracle JVM 64bit -Xmx28G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC , of which about 5GB are used.
I ran the two different variants several dozens of times and the results are pretty clear. The runtime difference is about 20%, the standard deviation of over 30 runs is about 1%. The program behaviour is correct in both versions.

How could this behaviour be explained? Could the JVM in-memory-reordering be the explanation or is there a known pitfall with increased number of arguments in methods? How can I find out?

**EDIT**

To answer some of the comments:

I started using [jitwatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch), seems very nice, but clearly very low level.

The timing shouldn't interfere, the timing/output methods are called only once every few seconds.

The buffer is a simply `long[3]` (other tests it varies from 2 to 15 or so). In one scenario, I did indeed keep a reference to the buffer in A, so GC was 0 as expected. However, even if I created the buffer anew in A with every call, GC still was 0 ... .

Comment: if you're using a profiler, try jmc instead. most profilers suffer either from safepoint bias or instrumentation bias. jmc uses some internal methods that allow it to obtain somewhat less biased samples. [jitwatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch) might also be useful if you want to dig deeper. beyond that the question might be too broad because it's mostly speculation-based.

Comment: Thanks. But no, I'm not using a profiler. After warming up, I simply log the times of each task to the console (each task takes a few seconds). But I use a little bit of local manual instrumentation to interrogate the GC activity.

Comment: you might want to use a profiler then. things like measuring time can already distort results on frequently called methods.

Comment: What kind of “buffer object” are we talking about? A primitive array, or rather an object eventually holding lots of references to other object created in either `C1` or `C2`? In the latter case, what happens to these objects *normally* between invocations of `B` and what happens now? Does that buffer object hold references between invocations of `B`.

Comment: GC might have gone down to 0 because you have still reference to the buffer in A. Where as in other case the buffer is local to B when it comes out of B buffer needs to be garbage collected.

Comment: How heavily loaded is your processor and is this multi threaded? This could be as simple as having removed the memory overhead from those methods makes them run a lot faster which then increases load on the system and causes something else (e.g. CPU) to become the bottleneck.

Comment: @TimB The process is single threaded (except for GC of course) and it is in-memory only. One CPU core is fully loaded in all version of the programm, even though I suspect the actual limitation is the memory bus. But as you said, it is possible that the additional argument causes the CPU cache lines to overflow or something like that.